# How can I solve RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (59) : device-side assert triggered error

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

There is a part that I cannot understand when I train the deep learning model on colab.

When I first train the model, measuring training loss and valid loss at the same time, it works for every batch and epoch.

However, when I train again in the same cell, or train another model in a different cell, `RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (59) : device-side assert triggered error` happens suddenly.

I also have tried this one at the very front of Colab window, but it didn't work

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = "1"

if os.environ.get('COLAB_GPU', '0') == '1':
  os.environ['GPU_NUM_DEVICES'] = '1'
  os.environ['XLA_FLAGS'] = '--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/usr/local/cuda/'
```

I don't think it is because of index error from loss function, because
if it was an index error, the first trial should not work!
[Here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1204) is be the link where I got information, but not being my case.

Is here anybody who can solve this problem?